# Change selected list view item image issue in android

Tags: android, listview

In my application i just using list view for displaying image and text. This is my adapter coding

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.name, arrList);

    listProductCategories.setAdapter(adapter);

    listProductCategories.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

              ImageView imgview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_listitem);
                 //And change its background here
                 imgview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fail);

            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + name, 10).show();

        }
    });
```

This is the screen shot for above coding.

[image]

Here i am highlighting the selected list items.But my output displays some of the many list view item image background changed..

Please give me a solution....

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_listitem" 
android:layout_width="20dp" 
android:layout_height="20dp" 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/next_unselect"
android:focusable="false" /> 
<TextView
android:id="@+id/name" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"   
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:focusable="false" 
android:text="TextView"
android:textColor="#003366" />
```

list item-

```
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_listitem" android:layout_width="20dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:background="@drawable/next_unselect" android:focusable="false" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/name" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:focusable="false" android:text="TextView" android:textColor="#003366" />
```

Comment: can you post `R.layout.list_item`

Comment: This is list_item:   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_listitem"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/next_unselect"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#003366" />

Comment: Please give me samples for my requirements..Highlighting selected list item image background

Comment: in ArrayAdapter, getView() method returns same instances of views if convertView is not null. so when you changing the image for a view, instances equal to that view also get effected...

Comment: @GopalRao Can u post some sample coding

Comment: use custom class called ItemHolder with getter and setter.

Comment: extend BaseAdapter class and inflate a new View every time in getView method irrespective of whether convertView is null or not... but this may slow your listview scrolling speed

Comment: @Android_kalai i will post a sample chekc it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used a Custom ListView with a Custom Adapter and a ItemsHolder class with getter and setters.

To change

1. Get the position of the item.
2. Change the item at the position.
3. Call`notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter to refresh listview.

Example:

```
ItemsHolder ih = hold.get(position);
ih.setImage(decodeImage(R.drawable.appicon));
ih.setName("Changed");
cus.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

test.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MenuActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView_Menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_List_Item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_List_Item"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<ItemsHolder> hold= new ArrayList<ItemsHolder>();
CustomAdapter cus;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    Bitmap[] images = {decodeImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher),decodeImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)};
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_Menu);
    hold.add(new ItemsHolder(images[0],"image1"));
    hold.add(new ItemsHolder(images[1],"image2"));
     cus = new CustomAdapter(hold);
     list.setAdapter(cus);
     list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
     {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View
                 view, int position, long id)
         {
                ItemsHolder ih = hold.get(position);
                ih.setImage(decodeImage(R.drawable.appicon));
                ih.setName("Changed");
                cus.notifyDataSetChanged();

         }
     });

}
private Bitmap decodeImage(int res) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),res);               
    return bitmap;      
}
class ItemsHolder
{
    Bitmap image;
    String name;
    public ItemsHolder(Bitmap bitmap, String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        image = bitmap;
        name =string;
    }
    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<ItemsHolder> list;
    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<ItemsHolder> list)
    {
        this.list=list;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder.iv= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_List_Item);
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        ItemsHolder ih = list.get(position);
        holder.iv.setImageBitmap(ih.getImage());
        holder.tv.setText(ih.getName());
        return convertView;
    }

}
class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView iv;
    TextView tv;
}
}
```

Snaps

[image]

[image]

Edit:

To your question in the comment

listbkg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 

        android:drawable="@drawable/appicon" />
    <item  android:state_focused="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</selector>
```

Then for ImageView in xml

```
android:background="@drawable/listbkg"
```

Comment: Yes the coding works fine..Thanks a lot..But i want a solution for another one issue.The image will be changed when the user user selects any list item.But here the problem is when user clicks another list item the previous selected image displays changed icon..

Comment: How to avoid the issues?At the time one and only selected list item image will be changed.

Comment: @Android_kalai i din't understand your problem

Comment: @Android_kalai you want only one item to change background on click is that what you want? Use a selector for that. No need for all these. Your question is confusing. the code i gave is meant to change the background of the item clicked and it persists.

Comment: My problem is,user select the first list item means first image will be changed.After that user select the second list item means second image will be changed.At the time the first and second images displays in changed state.

Comment: yes it is meant to work that way. If that is not what your looking for then your looking fro highlighting list item on clikc right? FOr that you can use selector

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39545/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-android-kalai)

Answer (score 0):

I could guess what might solve your problem. But first, I strongly recommend you watch this great video presentation from the chief architect of Android's ListView APIs (if you haven't):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: Yes..But i want some more quick solutions for my problem.